# How to access shopware app configuration in JavaScript file?

Tags: shopware6

how do I access the shopware app (not plugin) configuration inside a JavaScript file. The way for twig files is:

```
{{ config('myApp.config')|json_encode() }}
```

What is the right way to do this in Resources/app/storefront/src located files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to pass the data from the template by using data attributes of the element you register your storefront JS plugin to. The plugin base offers automatic setting of the `options` property, based on a naming convention. This can be done by adding the `-options` suffix to a data attribute, named according to the plugin name, and using valid JSON for the value.

```html
{% set myPluginData = config('myApp.config') %}

<div data-my-custom-plugin="true"
     data-my-custom-plugin-options="{{ myPluginData|json_encode }}">
</div>
```

```js
class MyCustomPlugin extends Plugin {
    init() {
        // should log your plugin config
        console.log(this.options);
    }

    // ...
}

PluginManager.register('MyCustomPlugin', MyCustomPlugin, '[data-my-custom-plugin]');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I used a workaround by using the template data attribute and in the JS I grabbed the element, because the plugin manager does not seem to work. Anyway it works, but not as shopware intends.